# Android timer count up starts from specific Time

Tags: android, counter

I want to Create time Counter Up that starts from current server time that i get it from a request and shown in TextView as in the image in **Current Time textView** .it only count up with no maximum range.

**How to do that?**

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate you question ?

Comment: Please explain              .

Comment: just i want to make counter up time it starts from current time , text view that show it changes every second